# styling html5's range control

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can i stylize html5's range control to like this screenshot

[image]

Comment: first search stackoverflow ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979297/is-there-a-way-to-style-html5s-range-control

Comment: This is like saying "How can I stylize html5's file control..."

Comment: @thephpdeveloper wrong. Styling the file control is forbidden because of security reasons.

Comment: Well I know that of course. Most of these html5 controls are currently experimental and their View is subjected to browser's specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do that. The spec doesn't define any formatting options. Live with the default look, or build your own using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the w3c article on "[A vocabulary and associated APIs for HTML and XHTML](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-input-accept)"  and scroll to: *4.10.7.1.14 Range state*.

And check this out: [jQuery style-able Range controls](http://flowplayer.org/tools/rangeinput/index.html).

**Edit:**

After your comment, see this in the article I linked:

HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" step="10" name="power" list="powers">
<datalist id="powers">
 <option value="0">
 <option value="-30">
 <option value="30">
 <option value="+50">
</datalist>
```

CSS:

```
input { height: 75px; width: 49px; background: #D5CCBB; color: black; }
```

Attempted at: [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/RfuC7/).

In chrome it appears as a horizontal range with no styles, in Opera as vertical range with no styles. in Firefox it appears as a `textarea` element with styles applied. I can't check IE because the download of IE9 broke it.

Comment: Not useful. I dont want to use jquery. Just need to know how to change bar color and thumb color.