# Styling HTML5's input range control with CSS?

Tags: css, html, input, slider, range

If so, how? I want to make the slider look like this:
[image]

Which involves changing the color of the draggable dot and the slider bar, as well as changing their sizes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You might have to use jQuery UI or something similar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979297/is-there-a-way-to-style-html5s-range-control

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can do it in WebKit for sure. here's a quick example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Nzgw/3/

pretty sure you can style cross-browser if you're using modernizr, @ least for modern browsers..but i am assuming. 
you can find more information here:
http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/implementing-iphone-slider-unlock-with-input-type-range