# Is there a way to style a range control for IE?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, slider

Is there a way to style a range control such that it degrades gracefully in IE8?

I've seen a way to style it for other HTML5 compatible browsers here:
[Is there a way to style HTML5's range control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979297/is-there-a-way-to-style-html5s-range-control)

But with the help on that page, the control does not show at all in IE8. Instead it only shows a textbox with the range value.

Comment: That inpit type isn't even supported in IE8 so I think you care going to have some issues. You would need full replacement option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Most browsers, which support this type of control also do support styling it. Only Opera below version 12 doesn't support styling it. Other browsers, like IE8 do not even support this control, so you will need a polyfill for it.

If you want you can try [webshims](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim). [Here is an example](http://rawgithub.com/aFarkas/webshim/69410b6e1fe23971e4a6fc6453bc544a36896f0d/demos/demos/webforms/styler/index.html), which uses different pseudo-element selectors to style native and polyfilled input[type="range"].

But to be honest, it is quite heavy to a) do fancy styling consitent x-browser and b) not all styles do work well with iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try your recommendations and give feedback at the earliest.